# Generate objects from JSON with Polymorphism

Tags: java, json, jackson, polymorphism

I have this JSON and I want to generate objects with it.

```
{
  "responseId": "response-id",
  "session": "projects/project-id/agent/sessions/session-id",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "End-user expression",
    "parameters": {
      "orderNumber": "PQL7648194AAAAA",
      "lastName": "RIVERO"
    },
    "action": "order",
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/project-id/agent/intents/intent-id",
      "displayName": "[InfoVuelo] Dia-hora de salida - datos de orden"
    },
    "languageCode": "es"
  },
  "originalDetectIntentRequest": {}
}
```

The fields of "parameters" are variable. For example for one situation parameters could be

```
{
  "parameters": {
     "email":"example@example.com"
  }
}
```

Also, I could have

```
{
"parameters": {
        "orderNumber": "PQL7648194AAAAA",
        "lastName": "RIVERO"
    }
}
```

I made a class `Parameters` and 2 classes(`OrderNumberAndLastNameParams` and `EmailParams`) that extends `Parameters`

```
public class EmailParams implements Parameters {
    private String email;
}  

public class OrderNumberLastNameParams implements Parameters {
    private String orderNumber;

    private String lastName;
}
```

My method to create objects with a given JSON file

```
public static <T> T buildBodyFromJson(String filePath, Class<T> clazz) {
    ObjectMapper myMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    T jsonMapper = null;
    try {
      jsonMapper = myMapper.readValue(new ClassPathResource(filePath).getInputStream(), clazz);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      fail(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return jsonMapper;
  }
```

But when I try to build the object, It tries to instantiate `Parameter` object instead of children objects getting `"Unrecognized field ... not marked as ignorable "`.

Comment: Hi, do you really have a need for the two different classes? What would be the trouble of using just the class Parameters containing all the three fields (email,orderNumber and lastName)?

Comment: I'm using that object to generate a requestbody and needs to have that structure. Without nulls or empty fields

Answer (score 0):

I'm understanding that you don't really need two separated classes, the problem is that you need to generate a requestbody with this object that doesn't have null / empty fields.
Well, there is an annotation that may help you.

Create a single class for paramters with all the 3 properties and annotate with @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)

```java
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Parameters  {
    private String email;
    private String orderNumber;
    private String lastName;
}
```

This annotation makes empty or null fields to not appears on the requestbody that you're creating.